# rotate fab and pre-5.0 the fab‘s shadow is cliped

Tags: android, material-design, floating-action-button

[origin image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfiVt.png)

[rotate FAB and the shadow is clipped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBCo1.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<objectAnimator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/overshoot_interpolator"
    android:duration="300"
    android:propertyName="rotation"
    android:valueFrom="135f"
    android:valueTo="0f" >
</objectAnimator>
```

the first animator

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<objectAnimator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/overshoot_interpolator"
    android:duration="300"
    android:propertyName="rotation"
    android:valueFrom="0f"
    android:valueTo="135f" >
</objectAnimator>
```

the second animator

```
mExpandMenuAnimator = (ObjectAnimator)AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(this,R.animator.fab_clockwise_animator);
mCollapsedMenuAnimator = (ObjectAnimator) AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(this,R.animator.fab_anticlockwise_animator);
mFab = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.home_fab);
mExpandMenuAnimator.setTarget(mFab);
mCollapsedMenuAnimator.setTarget(mFab);
mFab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (i == 0){
                i = 1;
                mCollapsedMenuAnimator.start();
            }else{
                i = 0;
                mExpandMenuAnimator.start();
            }
        }
});
```

FAB is support lib FAB, and how to solove the shadow clipped problem,
or  just rotate the src drawable doesn't rotate all of FAB, but how to do it?

Comment: why the image doesn't show?

Comment: Could you record the animation? You can record from Android Studio while connected via ADB (If you have Android 4.4 and above).